# Categorization in Google My Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to get categorization of a gpx file in **Google my maps** by elevation. Something like this:

[image]

When I import gpx file I am able to get displayed elevation attribute of the whole route and from first and last point. I guess its because of automatic calculation of the software with which I recorded map. I guess that this photo above, which was done with online software http://maplorer.com/view_gpx.html probably does some interpolation.

I am explicitly looking for a manual solutions, not coded one.

Comment: like http://hgoebl.github.io/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/demo/ ?

Comment: this is very neat solution when coding, however i am looking for manual solution. I have classified track_points by elevation in QGIS for example but i am not able to make line from that points. I hoped I can easily achive this in Google my maps

Comment: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/profile_input will help